# How to account for rotation with dist() in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to write a basic code for the moment that displays the distance between two objects in 3D space. I've created two boxes, and using sliders, I can change their translation. Using the dist() function, I can calculate the distance between them. This displays onto the canvas. However, when one box rotates about a certain point, the distance doesn't change, despite the box getting closer to the other.

I'm not too sure how exactly to incorporate the angle into this. I know *why* `dist()` doesn't change with angle (the variables I used in `dist()` I used to change the translation of the boxes, the variable I use for the angle is not used in `dist()`) but I'm not too certain how to account for rotation.

```
function draw() {
    background(255);
    lights();
    orbitControl();

    stroke('red');
    var x1 = Box1Slider.value();
    var z2 = Box2Slider.value();
    var RotVal = RotSlider.value();

    translate(x1, y1, z1)
    box(10,10,10) //box1
    translate(-x1,-y1,-z1)

    rotateY(RotVal); //box 2 rotates around y about origin
    translate(x2, y2,z2);
    box(10,10,10);  //box2

    let d = int(dist(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2));

    distance = createInput('')
    distance.position(80,100);
    distance.size(30);
    distance.value(d);
}
```

The variables Box1Slider.value() and Box2Slider.value() were renamed just to make it easier to see how they were changing the translation. These values are changed with sliders.

I'm hoping to account for RotVal in the distance. Currently, it makes no difference despite the distance of the boxes increasing and decreasing with rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`x2`, `y2`, `z2`) is not the final position of the 2nd box. You have to calculate the new x and z component of the vector (`x2`, `y2`, `z2`) after the rotation around the y-axis.
Create a 2 dimensional vector (`x2`, `z2`) by [`createVector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) and rotate it with [`.rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/rotate) by the angle `RotVal`.
Calculate the distance form (`x1`, `y1`, `z1`) to the rotated vector (`r_x2`, `y2`, `r_z2`):

```js
let v_xz2 = createVector(x2, z2).rotate(-RotVal) 
let r_x2  = v_xz2.x;
let r_z2  = v_xz2.y;

let d = int(dist(x1, y1, z1, r_x2, y2, r_z2));
```

See the example:

```js
var Box1Slider, Box2Slider, RotSlider, distance;

var x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0;
var x2 = 0, y2 = 0, z2 = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 250, WEBGL);

    Box1Slider = createSlider(0, 100, 50);
    Box1Slider.position(20, 20);
    Box2Slider = createSlider(0, 100, 50);
    Box2Slider.position(20, 50);
    RotSlider = createSlider(0, 360, 0);
    RotSlider.position(20, 80);
    distance = createInput('')
    distance.position(80,100);
    distance.size(30);
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    lights();
    orbitControl();
    rotateX(Math.PI/2)

    stroke('red');
    var x1 = Box1Slider.value();
    var z2 = Box2Slider.value();
    var RotVal = RotSlider.value() * Math.PI / 180.0;

    translate(x1, y1, z1)
    box(10,10,10) //box1
    translate(-x1,-y1,-z1)
      
    rotateY(RotVal); //box 2 rotates around y about origin
    translate(x2, y2, z2);
    box(10,10,10);  //box2

    let v_xz2 = createVector(x2, z2).rotate(-RotVal) 
    let r_x2  = v_xz2.x;
    let r_z2  = v_xz2.y;

    let d = int(dist(x1, y1, z1, r_x2, y2, r_z2));
    distance.value(d);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
```